# How to make a shell script to show the latest change in text file

Tags: file, shell, filesystems

I am using the following script to open a file and replace a string then saving it.

Sed s/old string/new string/g filename > filename1
MV filename1 filename

So I want to know is it possible to display the line where above script made changes in file so that I can make sure changes done properly....

Thanks a ton i n advance.

Regards,
Arun

Answer (score 1):

Try using the diff command

```
sed 's/old string/new string/g' filename > filename1;diff filename1 filename; mv filename1 filename
```

Comment: Thanks....can you tell me how to ask for conformation before executing MV command in above script....

Comment: You can either use the build in command "yes" and pipe it to the mv command or you could echo "yes" and again pipe it to the mv command.

Comment: sed 's/old string/new string/g' filename > filename1;diff filename1 filename;echo 'yes'| mv filename1 filename